# javascript() onclick hide element - doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript that onclick shows and hides element defining `style.display = "inherit";`
And `style.display = "none";`..

' Hide ' function also is running when ESC button is pressed..
Everything works fine in CHROME, OPERA etc.. except FIREFOX..

```
    window.onload=function() {
    document.body.onkeyup = key_event;
    }

    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "inherit";
        event.stopPropagation();
     }

    function hideDiv() {
         var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
         if (event.currentTarget == target) {
                 document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "none";
         }
     }

    function key_event(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) hideDiv();
        }
```

showDiv() works, but hideDiv doesn't..

HTML:

```
 <div id="PhotoFull" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.75); display:none; z-index: 999;" onclick="hideDiv()">
      <div style='width: 1000px'>
            SOME CONTENT
      </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5e6ww93h/2/

Thanks for attention

Comment: Hello, html added ;)

Comment: Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5e6ww93h/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntaxically, you have to pass the event obj to your hideDiv function

```
function hideDiv(event) {
     var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
     if (event.currentTarget == target) {
             document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "none";
     }
 }

function key_event(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) hideDiv(e);
}
```

Comment: Hello, i tryed it, but doesn't work anyway.. I made the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5e6ww93h/ thanks for attention

Comment: Why do you check `event.currentTarget == target`?

Comment: inside of PhotoFull is <div> </div>.. Without it hideDiv is executing when the user clicks on this child DIV.. I updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5e6ww93h/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
  window.onload=function() {
    document.body.onkeyup = key_event;
    }

    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "inherit";
        event.stopPropagation();
     }

    function hideDiv(e) {

         var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

         if (e.currentTarget == target) {
                 document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "none";
         }
     }

    function key_event(e) {   
        if (e.keyCode == 27)
                       hideDiv(e);
               }
```

fiddler:- http://jsfiddle.net/5e6ww93h/4/

Comment: Hello, thanks for attention. In this case, clicking outside of the box doesn't execute hideDiv

Comment: I think it will work on your page. Fiddler box are different panel for diff lang.. Did you try this on your page

Comment: I tried it on some sample page.. and its work.. Can you try above code on some sample html page, instead of fiddler?

Comment: thanks for attention.. I tryed your code in my page, but did not work.. Code offered by @huggilou seems working.. Thanks for your time once again